Unity URP Tessellation Shader Error After Built-up(Only)
I'm struggling with one strange problem. My urp project's tessellation shader doesn't work after I build it.
I tried to use the tessellation shader (follow some tutorials and modified) to create the grass in Unity.
Every thing works well until I build the project.
Grass using tessellation shader in Unity Editor - normal in editor
After Build-up the project,it's meeting compiling error
Also I tried to get the error message, but nothing appears in C:/users/Appdata/../Player.log when I tried to check the game log.
I also tried to use support then found its' compilation failed when the shader used in the real game:
CODE
renderer.material.shader = grassShader;
if (grassShader == null)
{
    Debug.LogError("Shader is missing in the Material!");
}
if (!grassShader.isSupported)
{
    Debug.LogError("Shader compilation failed: " + grassShader.name);
    return;
}

ENDCODE
The result image
Simple error message when running
So I'm wondering that is the reason for CG API and HLSL API
or maybe the platform?But my computer is lenovo using NVIDIA 3050,using DX11 and it should work.?
Here is my core grass shader and the tessellation shader used,
really hoping for some specific reason I can get! :)
Tessellation.hlsl:

#ifndef MY_TESSELLATION_INCLUDED
#define MY_TESSELLATION_INCLUDED

struct a2v
{
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 tangent : TANGENT;
};

struct v2f
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float4 tangent : TANGENT;
};
struct TessellationFactors
{
    float edge[3] : SV_TessFactor;
    float inside : SV_InsideTessFactor;
};

a2v vert(a2v v)
{
    return v;
}

v2f tessVert(a2v v)
{
    v2f o;
    o.pos = v.vertex;
    o.normal = v.normal;
    o.tangent = v.tangent;
    return o;
}
float _TessellationUniform;
TessellationFactors patchConstantFunction(InputPatch<a2v, 3> patch, uint patchID: SV_PrimitiveID)
{
    TessellationFactors f;
    f.edge[0] = _TessellationUniform;
    f.edge[1] = _TessellationUniform;
    f.edge[2] = _TessellationUniform;
    f.inside = _TessellationUniform;
    return f;
}

[domain("tri")]
[outputcontrolpoints(3)]
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[partitioning("integer")]
[patchconstantfunc("patchConstantFunction")]
[maxtessfactor(64.0f)]
a2v hull(InputPatch<a2v, 3> patch, uint id : SV_OutputControlPointID)
{
    // return one a2v patch
    return patch[id];
}
[domain("tri")]
v2f domain(TessellationFactors factors, OutputPatch<v2f, 3> patch, float3 barycentricCoordinates : SV_DomainLocation)
{
    a2v v;

    #define MY_DOMAIN_PROGRAM_INTERPOLATE(a2vName, v2fName) v.a2vName = \
        patch[0].v2fName * barycentricCoordinates.x + \
        patch[1].v2fName * barycentricCoordinates.y + \
        patch[2].v2fName * barycentricCoordinates.z;

    MY_DOMAIN_PROGRAM_INTERPOLATE(vertex, pos)
    MY_DOMAIN_PROGRAM_INTERPOLATE(normal, normal)
    MY_DOMAIN_PROGRAM_INTERPOLATE(tangent, tangent)

    return tessVert(v);
}
#endif // MY_TESSELLATION_INCLUDED

Core for the grass shader:
...
// sample the FlowMap by time
float2 uv = pos.xz * _WindDistortionMap_ST.xy + _WindDistortionMap_ST.zw
    + _WindFrequency * _Time.y;
float2 windSample = (SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D_LOD(_WindDistortionMap, sampler_WindDistortionMap, uv, 0.0).xy*2 - 1) * _WindStrength;
// flowmap(windMap) calculates the wind direction
float3 wind = normalize(float3(windSample.x + _WindTargetModifier.x, windSample.y + _WindTargetModifier.y, 0));
// Rotate by windMap
float3x3 windRotation = RotateAroundAxis3x3(C_HALF_PI * length(windSample), wind);

// z = Unity_y; x = -Unity_z; y = Unity_x
// Rotate one random angle in the tangent space
float3x3 facingRotationMatrix = RotateAroundAxis3x3((GetRandomNum(pos.xy)*C_2PI), float3(0, 0, 1));
// Take a random bend
float3x3 bendRotationMatrix = RotateAroundAxis3x3(GetRandomNum(pos.xzx) * _BendRotationRandom * C_HALF_PI, float3(-1, 0, 0));

float3x3 windMatrix = mul(tangentToLocal, windRotation);
float3x3 localMatrix = mul(windMatrix, facingRotationMatrix);
float3x3 transformationMatrix = mul(localMatrix, bendRotationMatrix);
float3x3 transformationMatrixFacing = mul(tangentToLocal, facingRotationMatrix);

float height =  _BladeHeightRandom * (GetRandomNum(pos.zyx)*2 - 1) + _BladeHeight;
float width = _BladeWidthRandom * (GetRandomNum(pos.xzy)*2 - 1) + _BladeWidth;
float forward = GetRandomNum(pos.yyz) * _BladeForward;
...


Really hoping for one kind solution!
